# Click on "onclick"-login-button using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, authentication, automated-tests, puppeteer

I'm experiencing difficulties using Puppeteer to automate a login for a webside that uses an "onclick" script to pop-up it's login window. The login-link looks like this:

```html
<li>
   <a href="#" onclick='openJqueryDialog("D_Login"); return false;' style="padding-right:0;">Login</a>
   <span class="blu">oder</span>
   <a href="/de/registrierung" onclick="addGTMEvent('Homepage', 'Clicks - Register')">Registrieren</a>
</li>
```

Unfortunately the page doesn't offer a login prompt that enables to address the login fields by its ID directly like shown in many puppeteer-examples. There is only the possibility to login using this pop-up window.
I tried many different approaches to get this login prompt opened up like:

```js
(await page.$$eval(selector, a => a.filter(a => a.textContent === 'Login')))[0].click();
```

or

```js
let selector = 'a';
         page.$$eval(selector, anchors => {
             anchors.map(anchor => {
                 if(anchor.textContent == 'Login') {
                     anchor.click();
                     return
                 }
                 })
         });
```

After these actions I expect to see this login window in the screenshot I do right after this using

```js
await page.screenshot({ path: screenshot2 });
```

I also tried to use its x-path using page.$x(). Unfortunately none of these worked. The screenshot that I took right after the action returned the same result of the page like right before the intended click. I expect to see the login window popped up on the screenshot. Might it be that the screenshot function doesn't show this window even though it would be visible?

Is there a way to see the browser in action while a puppeteer script is executed? I did some experiments using

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless:false });
```

But this didn't show any browser window. So currently I only have the screenshots as a return value.

Unfortunately I'm not too familiar with JavaScript...

How can I achieve to get this link clicked?

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way: Selenium + python. Works right away. Awesome debugging functionalities. Supports Firefox as well. Easier syntax. Less Brainfuck.